# Regex replace + in string with blank

Tags: c#, regex

How do I replace all alpha characters and plus signs using regex in C#?

For example, the input is:

> below -10
>       +20

Expected output:

> -10
>       20

My current regex is:

```
[A-Za-z ]
```

Comment: The answers given are correct. If they're not solving your issue, you'll need to show us how you're using the regex and displaying the result so we can figure out why not.

Comment: @LaLa: I added sample code to my answer, I think that now you will easily identify what is missing in your code. Note that you'd better include the whole regex-related C# code in the question from the start to get a prompt and correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Unicode character classes in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and use

```
[\p{L}\p{Zs}+]
```

Where `\p{L}` stands for any Unicode letter, and `\p{Zs}` for any Unicode space. `+` inside the character class is treated as a literal.

See [RegexStorm demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5Cp%7BL%7D%5Cp%7BZs%7D%2B%5D&i=below%20-10%0D%0A%2B20&r=) (go to Context or Split list tabs to see actual replacements).

Here is sample working code (tested in VS2012):

```
var rx = new Regex(@"[\p{L}\p{Zs}+]");
var result = rx.Replace("below -10\r\n+20", string.Empty);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, however I get an unrecognized escape sequence relating to the \p

Comment: I added an @ sign to get around above error but still not replacing the +.

Comment: In C# code, you need to use the verbatim string literal: `var rx = new Regex(@"[\p{L}\p{Zs}+]");`. As you see in my example code, the `+` symbol got replaced.

Answer (score 1):

```
[A-Za-z+ ]
```

This should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression exclude replace : [^0-9-].
It will remove all chars other than number and minus sign

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = String.Concat("below -10", Environment.NewLine, "+20");
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "[A-Za-z +]", String.Empty);
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).